# Django form posting does nothing

Tags: django, forms

I'm making an Image posting form with thes fields: Title, Description, Image file, and a public or not boolean. The issue I have is that it does nothing. It seems to post as I can see it in the dev server console, but then nothing, no image in media/photos, nothing in the database either... Weird thing is that when I create an Image object from the django admin page, It works perfectly fine. So it must be in the view or template, but I may be wrong. Here's the code:

```
<!--The template-->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h1>Ajouter une image</h1>
    <h2>Deconnexion:</h2><a href="/Gallery/Disconnect/">Ici</a>
    <p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_titre">Titre:</label>
    <input id="id_titre" type="text" name="Titre" maxlength="100" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="Description" id="id_description" ></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="id_i">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="Image" id="id_i" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_public"><input type="checkbox" name="public" id="id_public"/>Public <!-- Attention, Internet est un lieu public, meme si cette case n'est pas cochée, votre image devient publique une fois postée. elle ne sera cependant pas affichée dans la gallerie aleatoire ou dernieres images. -->
    </label></p>
     <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </p>
    {% if sauvegarde %}
    <p>Image saved.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <h1>Connect</h1>
        {% if error %}
        <p><strong>wrong password, or user does not exist, sorry</strong></p>
        {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form><h1>Or Register <a href="/Gallery/Register/">here</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

The View:

```
#The view
def Publish(request):
    reg = False
    sauvegarde = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ImagePublish(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                pic = Image()
                pic.titre = form.cleaned_data["titre"]
                pic.description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
                pic.i = form.cleaned_data["i"]
                pic.public = form.cleaned_data["public"]
                pic.save()

                sauvegarde = True
            else:
                form = ImagePublish(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else :
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data["username"]  # Nous récupérons le nom d'utilisateur
                password = form.cleaned_data["password"]  # … et le mot de passe
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  #Nous vérifions si les données sont correctes
                if user:  # Si l'objet renvoyé n'est pas None
                    login(request, user)  # nous connectons l'utilisateur
                else: #sinon une erreur sera affichée
                        error = True
        else:
            form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'Publier.html',locals())
```

The form:

```
#The form
class ImagePublish(forms.Form):
    titre = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_content(self):
        if content != None:
            content = self.cleaned_data['content']
            content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
            if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES:
                if content._size > int(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE):
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content._size)))
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'File type is not supported'))
            return content
    public = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

That's it, I can add any other part of the code you need and everything is imported, also I would like to point the fact that I got no error, and the message I set to say like "cool, Image uploaded" doesn't show up, If that can show anyone the good direction...

Comment: IMHO, having the same URL processing two types of forms depending if the user is logged in or not is not very good.The view code for this page would be useful.

Comment: well, It worked til now, but I understand, anyway it's also the simpliest way I found. are you requesting the full views.py code?

Comment: no, only the view for this page. as a sidenote, you should use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), not straight HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, Using like {{ form.as_p }} or {{ form }}? I started doing that at the biggining and had odd behaviors so I took the habits of making my forms in html directly, however when I use it in this case it changes nothing... The view is already there, I'm truly sorry but I don't get what you want me to give

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your entire code below the template. I've edited the post.

Comment: my bad, I didn't published it properly. I think it comes from the view, as I can publish from admin page and modifying the code as in dhana's answer doesn't lead to improvements, does it make sense?

Comment: I think using the handmade form + processing in the view create the problem. You could put `print` statements (or, you may debug the code with a breakpoint) in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue, actually it was the auteur field that didn't fill itself with connected user, so it didn't validate cause it was empty and the Image wasn't posting. I just added "pic.auteur = request.user" in my view and it did it. If you need it just ask and I'll post the new code! bye

Comment: Hey, wondering can you please post the new code? It would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding stuff from admin, then you must have a model. In that case, you need to use `ModelForm` for the form and use @dhana's approach, not doing it manually (admin interface does it via ModelForm afaik.

You may want to use the `{{form}}` and render the errors like `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. This way you can see what's wrong.

You may want to start from a simple form (without all the validation code).

Comment: Using {{ form.non_field_errors }} doesn't give any error, when posting the view just release a new empty form. The "error" was already here before the validation has been setup, I doubt It will change something removing it but I'll give a try. Actually, The error started when I implemented the booleanfield for public, I feel stupid I didn't mention it before but if it can be helpful... Thanks a lot

Comment: After your brilliant suggestion of commenting the code with prints, it turns out that the "if form.is_valid():" condition isn't met, I'll try to look for what's wrong according to this,  thanks again

Comment: I wonder if you need to put the boolean field at the beginning of the form class... Also, shouldn't you have a field called `i` in the form and have `clean_i` instead of `clean_content`?

Comment: well in that case it would mean to have also the other fields, I thought content was doing all the field? I'm not sure how to implement that clean_i however, but I'll give a try, I also placed the boolean on top, I don't know if it will do any good but it can't cause any issue so it doesn't cost anything to try

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering the empty form to html using django forms at GET request. Like this,

**GET Request:**

```
form = ImagePublish()

return render(request, 'Publier.html',locals())
```

django template Publier.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Then submitting form is post request,

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    form = ImagePublish(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import Image
    class ImagePublish(forms.ModelForm): # This is my change
        class Meta:
           model = Image
        def clean_content(self):
            if content != None:
                content = self.cleaned_data['content']
                content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
                if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES:
                    if content._size > int(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE):
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content._size)))
                else:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'File type is not supported'))
                return content
```

Comment: well, thanks a lot. Now at least, I have an error: "AttributeError at /Gallery/Publish/
'ImagePublish' object has no attribute 'save'". After some changes, It appears that the origin is the form.save() line, so It's a progress, but I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change in forms.py `forms.Form` should be `forms.ModelForm`. I updated my post.

Comment: sadly, back to the first issue... I keep working on it, maybe I missed something

Comment: check the database your data is added or not after submitting the form. because you are rendering same html page after successful form submission.So it is showing every time form.

Comment: I browsed the DB and my images added with admin page are inside, and not the ones from the publish template form. I'll try to delete the DB and do a syncdb again    -edit- recreatind the database didn't work; still looking for a way to solve the problem