# Is there a way to exclude a BooleanField from django's form.is_valid?

Tags: django, forms, model

Well, on my way to solve that problem: [Django form posting does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130816/django-form-posting-does-nothing?noredirect=1#comment35370408_23130816) It turns out that the issue may come from the checkbox input wich doesnt validate the form.is_valid condition. This is why I want to skip that step. Replacing handwritten template form by {{ form }} didn't work, and giving the booleanfield a blank=true argument neither. Thanks in advance, feel free to ask whatever could help. Bye

-----------------------------------------------**Template**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!--The template-->
    <h1>Ajouter une image</h1>
    <h2>Deconnexion:</h2><a href="/Gallery/Disconnect/">Ici</a>
    <p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_titre">Titre:</label>
    <input id="id_titre" type="text" name="Titre" maxlength="100" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="Description" id="id_description" ></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="id_i">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="Image" id="id_i" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_public"><input type="checkbox" name="public" id="id_public"/>Public <!-- Attention, Internet est un lieu public, meme si cette case n'est pas cochée, votre image devient publique une fois postée. elle ne sera cependant pas affichée dans la gallerie aleatoire ou dernieres images. -->
    </label></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </p>
    {% if sauvegarde %}
    <p>Image saved.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <h1>Connect</h1>
        {% if error %}
        <p><strong>wrong password, or user does not exist, sorry</strong></p>
        {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form><h1>Or Register <a href="/Gallery/Register/">here</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

-----------------------------------------------**View**

```
def Publish(request):
reg = False
sauvegarde = False
print("you did it at first")
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    print("you did it then")
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("are you kidding me?")
        form = ImagePublish(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("I'll drink one more Burn if that message doesn't show up")
            form.save()
            print("you did it") 
            #pic = Image()
            #pic.titre = form.cleaned_data["titre"]
            #pic.description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            #pic.i = form.cleaned_data["i"]
            #pic.public = form.cleaned_data["public"]
            #pic.save()

            sauvegarde = True
        else:
            form = ImagePublish()
else :
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]  # Nous récupérons le nom d'utilisateur
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]  # … et le mot de passe
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  #Nous vérifions si les données sont correctes
            if user:  # Si l'objet renvoyé n'est pas None
                login(request, user)  # nous connectons l'utilisateur
            else: #sinon une erreur sera affichée
                    error = True
    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

return render(request, 'Publier.html',locals())
```

-----------------------------------------------**Form**

```
class ImagePublish(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Image
def clean_content(self):
    if content != None:
        content = self.cleaned_data['content']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES:
            if content._size > int(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE):
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content._size)))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'File type is not supported'))
    return content
```

-----------------------------------------------**Model**

```
class Image(models.Model):
titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(null=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de parution")
i = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")
public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
auteur = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') 



def __unicode__(self):

    return u"%s" % self.titre
```

Comment: How about a default value?

Comment: What is strange is that the value (checked or unchecked) doesnt affect the validation problem, it does not validate wether the checkbox is checked or unchecked, but I'll give a try, thanks!

Comment: from your other question it appears you have `required=False` on the boolean field in the form, so it won't be validated.  This question does not have enough info in it to give an answer

Comment: if you have a validation error that doesn't seem to come from any of your fields, ensure that you are outputting `form.non_field_errors` in your template so you can see the error message https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Comment: I thought about the foreignkey object: could it be a problem? I mean, it is not in the template form as it is linked to the auth model, but the validation may fail when validating that field?

Comment: it's hard to say if you don't post the relevant code for people to see

Comment: Edited with the latest changes

Comment: your `auteur` field will be required as it is not null in the model and not excluded from the form, but you have not put that field into the template so I'd expect it to cause validation error

Comment: Then should I exlude it from the form validation or make it required=false? I don't really know how to solve this, I'll make searches on the web and try several things, but if you may give me hints it would be fine, thanks a lot, bye.